# Less CSS "max" function not working on list

Tags: css, less, frontend

I have a parametric mixin called ".align" that takes one argument that is a list of heights:

```
.align(@parent, @child, @heights) ...
```

I call the function as such:

```
.align(rectangle, img, 154px 152px 166px 166px 159px 112px);
```

I get the error "Operation on an invalid type" when the function is called this way. I have isolated the problem to this piece of code within ".align":

```
@highest-height: max(@heights);
```

This is very strange to me, because 1. I have done almost the exact same thing before and 2. Because when I put the list of heights (154px 152px 166px 166px 159px 112px) inside the mixin, rather than passing it through the mixin, it works fine in the "max" function.

Answer (score 0):

(*Temporary answer:*)
This minimal test compiles as expected (Less 1.7.4):

```
x {
    .align(rectangle, img, 154px 152px 166px 166px 159px 112px);
    y: @highest-height;
}

.align(@parent, @child, @heights) {
    @highest-height: max(@heights);    
}
```

So the problem is elsewhere. In fact `max` function itself can't generate such error message, usually "Operation on an invalid type" is thrown for arithmetic expressions with invalid operands (something like `(1 + a)`). So I guess we need more parts of your code to find out what's wrong.